# issue with importing Pymc3

Tags: python, import, cython, pymc3, arviz

I am trying to import PyMC3 but unfortunately there is some kind of clash withe one of the libraries already installed:

```
import pymc3

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-200e74b8195d> in <module>()
----> 1 import pymc3

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc3\__init__.py in <module>()
     11 from .model_graph import model_to_graphviz
     12 from . import ode
---> 13 from .stats import *
     14 from .sampling import *
     15 from .step_methods import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc3\stats\__init__.py in <module>()
      8 import warnings
      9 
---> 10 import arviz as az
     11 
     12 def map_args(func):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arviz\__init__.py in <module>()
     25 
     26 from .rcparams import rcParams, rc_context
---> 27 from .data import *
     28 from .plots import *
     29 from .stats import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arviz\data\__init__.py in <module>()
      1 """Code for loading and manipulating data structures."""
----> 2 from .inference_data import InferenceData, concat
      3 from .io_netcdf import from_netcdf, to_netcdf
      4 from .datasets import load_arviz_data, list_datasets, clear_data_home
      5 from .base import numpy_to_data_array, dict_to_dataset, CoordSpec, DimSpec

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arviz\data\inference_data.py in <module>()
      4 from copy import copy as ccopy, deepcopy
      5 from datetime import datetime
----> 6 import netCDF4 as nc
      7 import numpy as np
      8 import xarray as xr

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\netCDF4\__init__.py in <module>()
      1 # init for netCDF4. package
      2 # Docstring comes from extension module _netCDF4.
----> 3 from ._netCDF4 import *
      4 # Need explicit imports for names beginning with underscores
      5 from ._netCDF4 import __doc__, __pdoc__

include\membuf.pyx in init netCDF4._netCDF4()

AttributeError: type object 'netCDF4._netCDF4._MemBuf' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

I have looked around at similar issues but I am not sure I fully understand how to approach this problem and I would appreciate some support in plain English :)

Comment: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1953#issuecomment-398128940 you need to ensure the right version of `PyMC3` is installed for the version of your python3.

Comment: I am not sure how to unpack Pymc3 distribution through PyPi, any guidance on that?